# ros2 tab completion not working after Bouncy

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before the Bouncy release I was developing my Ada client library against some ROS2 indeterminate rolling status, built from source (last checked out about a month ago). I was using ament at the time. Last time I tried, tab completion worked with the ros2 executable; both my packages and the executables within were offered and could be run.

After upgrading to Bouncy (from source, latest stable) tab completion no longer works. Neither the packages nor executables appear on hitting tab. Furthermore, even if I write a proper launch command, it says the package does not exist. Unfortunately, I'm not 100% sure I haven't changed anything important in my CMake files. On the other hand, I'm not sure either how one has to create executables so they're known to tab completion. I'm using plain cmake build method, with `add_executable` (which used to work).

Here is a sequence of compilation/sourcing:

```
$ cd ada4bouncy/
$ source ../ros2_bouncy/install/setup.bash   # ros2 installation from source
$ colcon build
Starting >>> rclada_common
Finished <<< rclada_common [3.89s]                      
Starting >>> rosidl_generator_ada
Finished <<< rosidl_generator_ada [15.70s]                        
Starting >>> rclada
Finished <<< rclada [13.37s]                        
Starting >>> rclada_examples
Finished <<< rclada_examples [6.12s]                        

Summary: 4 packages finished [39.34s]
$ source install/setup.bash 
$ find install -name rclada_selftest  # Check the executable is where it should be
install/rclada/lib/rclada/rclada_selftest
$ ros2 run rclada rclada_selftest  # This fails
Package 'rclada' not found
```

argcomplete is version 1.8.1 from Ubuntu:

```
$ apt policy python3-argcomplete 
python3-argcomplete:
  Installed: 1.8.1-1ubuntu1
```

that matches the version offered by pip:

```
$ pip show argcomplete
Name: argcomplete
Version: 1.8.1
```

Any ideas on how to further diagnose this matter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296464/ros2-tab-completion-not-working-after-bouncy/) by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-05**:
In further testing I've created two dummy packages via `ros2 pkg create` and completion works when build method is `ament_cmake` but not for plain `cmake`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want your custom package to appear in the completion you need to make sure to "register" it in the resource index. For that you need to install an empty file to `<prefix>/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/<pkgname>`.

`ament_cmake` is just doing that for you when you invoke `ament_package()` in your CMake code (see https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/fd3d09b351b88d33daa320314b178f253ccfb172/ament_cmake_core/cmake/index/ament_index_register_package.cmake#L29).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
I will try that, thanks. Is there any chance that regular CMake install(EXPORTS) or export() where somehow doing that, or something else that was detected? Because I never did what you suggest (nor anything related to ament) and I had it working for some time.

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
The empty file wasn't enough, nor directly calling `ament_index_register_package(PACKAGE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})` did the trick, so I guess there was something more under the wraps? In the end I've moved to ament_cmake build type in all of my packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My tab completion can complete some first args, but the second args usually work not good.

Are there some ways to refresh my bouncy and workspace packages and make tab completion  work better ?

---

Originally posted by [itfanr](https://answers.ros.org/users/34867/itfanr/) with karma: 61 on 2018-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1